# How to import node package in django static file(any custom js file in static folder)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, django, django-templates, node-modules

I am attempting to incorporate the wallet connect functionality into my project using the available npm package, but I am experiencing an error stating 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'. The node_modules folder for my project is currently located within the static folder. How can I properly import and utilize the wallet connect package in my project?

*both imports are not happening in following code.

```
import WalletConnect from "static/node_modules/@walletconnect/client/dist/umd/index.min.js";
import QRCodeModal from "@walletconnect/qrcode-modal";

// Create a connector
const connector = new WalletConnect({
  bridge: "https://bridge.walletconnect.org", // Required
  qrcodeModal: QRCodeModal,
});

// Check if connection is already established
if (!connector.connected) {
  // create new session
  connector.createSession();
}
```

if more information is required then tell me in comment section, I'll update my question with that information. Thank you!

Comment: You can't use import without transpiling your code.

Comment: @RingoldsLeščinskis What else i can do to make it work ?

Comment: You need to transpile your code using Webpack or something else. Also you're importing node modules wrong.

Comment: @RingoldsLeščinskis can you share the link of some website where i can transpile this code ?

Comment: Look into using webpack. There are many youtube videos about this topic.